# Who decides what optional dependencies to install when installing nodejs-polars using `npm`?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependency-management

```
{
  "name": "c-qube",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "date-fns-tz": "^2.0.0",
    "fast-memoize": "^2.5.2",
    "ioredis": "^5.3.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "nestjs-pino": "^3.1.2",

     ...

    "nodejs-polars": "^0.7.2",
    "nodejs-polars-linux-x64-gnu": "^0.7.2",

     ...

    "pg": "^8.10.0",
    "picocolors": "^1.0.0",
    "pino-http": "^8.3.3",
  },
}
```

Basically there’s a open source project that I’m working on, which has the package.json as shown, the `nodejs-polars-linux-x64-gnu` has been explicitly added as a dependency. This was causing an error on my mac.

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for nodejs-polars-linux-x64-gnu@0.7.4: wanted {"os":"linux","cpu":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","cpu":"arm64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid os:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual os:  darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid cpu:  x64
npm ERR! notsup Actual cpu: arm64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2023-07-07T08_57_21_501Z-debug-0.log
```

I wanted to remove it & see if the project build throws any errors, fortunately it worked fine & didn’t throw any errors (local environment, mac mini with M1).

Up on seeing the dependency tree, I realised that `nodejs-polars-linux-x64-gnu` was marked optional.

```
├─┬ nodejs-polars@0.7.2
│ ├── nodejs-polars-darwin-arm64@0.7.2
│ ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY nodejs-polars-darwin-x64@0.7.2
│ ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY nodejs-polars-linux-arm64-gnu@0.7.2
│ ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY nodejs-polars-linux-x64-gnu@0.7.2
│ ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY nodejs-polars-win32-ia32-msvc@0.7.2
│ └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY nodejs-polars-win32-x64-msvc@0.7.2
```

I wanted to know

1. “Out of the the 6 optional dependencies”, is one picked & installed based on the host hardware & OS by `nodejs-polars` on the fly? (and other five are ignored?)
2. Or should the developer add some configuration to handle this?
3. or should the Devs manually keep modifying the package.json as the OS & hardware changes?

Answer (score 1):

the OS specific binary should not be specified by the end user. The n-api framework used by nodejs-polars will auto detect which binary should be used & install it accordingly.